# Sortation vs Sorting?

Tags: differences, nouns, adjectives

Is there any significant difference between *sortation* and *sorting*?

Amazon's local distribution center is called "Amazon Sortation Center". I hadn't seen *sortation* used before.

Comment: What do dictionaries have to say?

Comment: The difference is lost on me, other than that sort can be a noun as well.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth the dictionaries I checked give definitions that don't provide differentiation.

Comment: [AHD and Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sortation) have caveats on usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Sortation* does exist, but means exactly the same as *sorting*. The OED has a page or so of explanation of the -ation and -tion suffixes, ending

> words in which -ation is, or seems to be, merely added to the verb,
>   are synonymous with the verbal substantive in -ing; already in 17th c.
>   the use of vexation, visitation, etc. instead of vexing, visiting,
>   etc. (flirtation, starvation had not yet been heard of) was ridiculed
>   thus: T. Randolph Amyntas i. iii. 9 in Poems (1638)    *The*. But what
>   languages Doe they speake, servant? *Mop.* Several languages, As
>   Cawation, Chirpation, Hootation. Whistleation, Crowation, Cackleation,
>   Shreekation, Hissation. *The.* And Fooleation.

Comment: *Sortation* is simply a more formal version of *sorting*, in my experience.  Other words can be used the same way; we could have, *e.g.*, a *collaboration exercise* or a *collaborating exercise*.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie I find *sortation* more pretentious than formal.

Comment: @Tim What do "*The*" and "*Mop*" in italics towards the end of your quote refer to?

Comment: Not to be confused with [*sortition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sortition).

Comment: @tchrist: *That's* what I was trying to find! I rather like the idea of "You have ordered from Amazon! Let's spin the wheel and find what you will receive..."

Comment: @Lawrence: Presumably character names; the point being that one person is trying to make *cawing* or *chirping* sound impressive, and the other is mocking him. Nothing changes...

Comment: @TimLymington Ah, I see. I thought they were standard OED abbreviations.

Comment: The word appears in some dictionaries (Collins, for example) and not in others (such as Cambridge English).  None give an explanation or even examples.  Interestingly, Etymonline has no entry for this word.  Is this usage an example of GW Bush's habit of turning English short words into long Latin ones?  And is the use of this word confined (at present) to the world of post office and delivery delivery specialisms?  I do no think the word pops up among the obvious 'sortation' candidates:  librarians and museum/gallery curators.

Comment: Curiously, the verb 'to sort' is not derived from the apparent cognate Latin root 'sors', which means fate chance or that which has been allotted (not sortated) by fate.  Consulting ones fate can be described, however, as 'sortition'.

Answer (score -1):

Do we conjuge? Or aggrege? I think someone somewhere got the real word wrong and covered it up by saying it's a more formal version. (A more perfect union...) Just like one's inability to be whelmed by any given situation, or the need to ever even know that the plural form of material is materiel, I can't get with "sortate."

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But form/formation, convoke/convocation, provoke/provocation, cease/cessation, salute/salutation (not salutate). Sometimes verbs have -ate, others they don't.

Comment: But you can conjugate (from Latin jugum = a yoke or joint) and congregate (from Latin grex - gregis = a herd or flock.